# Easiest way to limit AWS Lambda invocations per hour

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have an API Gateway invoking an AWS Lambda which sends Text messages.
In case of an accident or an attack, I would like to limit the max invocations per hour to mitigate the cost of an infinite loop for example.

What is the easiest way to do that ? I can't see such options in AWS Lambda, SQS or event Cloudwatch Alarm

Answer (score 3):

API Gateway supports [rate limiting](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-request-throttling.html). You can set limits for individual API stages or methods and you can enable usage plans to restrict client request submissions to within specified request rates and quotas.

In addition, per the [API Gateway FAQ](https://aws.amazon.com/api-gateway/faqs/):

> API Gateway automatically protects your backend systems from distributed denial-of-service (DDoS) attacks, whether attacked with counterfeit requests (Layer 7) or SYN floods (Layer 3).

And, finally, be aware of [Protecting API Endpoints](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/whitepapers/latest/aws-best-practices-ddos-resiliency/protecting-api-endpoints-bp4.html) guidance.